# VBScript to save a webpage with login required

Tags: vbscript

I am looking for a vbscript that can get a webpage and save it as a file to my pc. I already found a code for that and the problem is that the website requires you to login (for example yahoomail.com). The code should not open a web browser. I just need the webpage saved to a file.

Here is the code i found:

```
Const adSaveCreateNotExist = 1
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
Const adTypeBinary = 1 'Binary data
Const adTypeText = 2 '(Default) Text data

URL = "www.yahoomail.com"
DiskFile = "C:\web\test.xml"

Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objMessage.CreateMHTMLBody URL
SaveToFile objMessage, DiskFile

Sub SaveToFile(Msg, Fn)
Dim Strm, Dsk

Set Strm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
Strm.Type = adTypeText
Strm.Charset = "US-ASCII"
Strm.Open
Set Dsk = Msg.DataSource
Dsk.SaveToObject Strm, "_Stream"
Strm.SaveToFile Fn, adSaveCreateOverWrite

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: Have you tried running this code? What happens when you do/what problem are you having?

Comment: It will produce a test.xml file which contains the page source (html codes) . However the xml file only contains the web page login. What I need is to go through the login page and I cannot seems to find any script or command to do that. As I stated above, the script should not need to open any web browser.

Comment: Or how can I insert somewhere in the line Strm.Open the required  username and password?

Comment: Can anyone please help me on this? Any script will do as long as it is accessible in any windows 7 pc's like vbscript, .bat. . Your help in anyway is much appreciated.